# How to use dd(debug_backtrace()); for an error debugging?

Tags: 7, debugging

I have this exact [error](https://www.drupal.org/node/1778572) on my site.

I am trying to troubleshoot the error using `dd(debug_backtrace());` through the Devel module as is described on the link above.

Being the noob on developing I can't figure out how to print the output in a `drupal_debug.txt` file under the `tmp` folder in the root of my Drupal Installation (As is described in the in the link above).

I have tried dd(debug_backtrace()); but I don't see any error file being created so I also tried  dd(debug_backtrace('drupal_debug.txt')); but I get the error:

> Warning: file_put_contents(): Only 0 of 1 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space in drupal_debug() (line 1793 of  /home/bigcypru/public_html/sites/all/modules/devel/devel.module).
>
> Devel was unable to write to `/tmp/drupal_debug.txt`.

I created the file manually and set 777 permissions to be sure is writable but still get the same error and I am sure I have enough space in my hosting plan.

Answer (score 1):

You can run:

```
dd(debug_backtrace());
```

which prints the output to `drupal_debug.txt` file by default in your temporary folder which can be found in your `tmp` folder (See: [Where Drupal creates temporary files?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/7639/1908)). You can specify different file, but in Drupal settings related to file system.

The call to <del>`dd(debug_backtrace('drupal_debug.txt'));`</del> is invalid, since [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) accepts int $options, not the file.

Regarding this warning:

> Only 0 of 1 bytes written, **possibly out of free disk space** in drupal_debug(). Devel was unable to write to `/tmp/drupal_debug.txt`.

it says you're likely to be out of free disk space on your hard drive. So you should remove this file from your temporary folder at `/tmp`, then try again.

To make it more light, use the following version:

```
dd(debug_backtrace(FALSE, 5));
```

which won't populate all objects (FALSE) and limit number of stack frames returned to 5.

If your function is called too many times, try adding `die()` or `exit();` to avoid multiple calls.

You can also use the following one-liner:

```
array_walk(debug_backtrace(),create_function('$a,$b','print "<pre>{$a[\'function\']}()(".basename($a[\'file\']).":{$a[\'line\']});</pre>\\n";'));
```

which will print even more minimalized version of the backtrace to avoid out-of-space issues.

Answer (score 1):

I also can recommend the [Past Log](https://www.drupal.org/project/past) module.

It offers you enhanced logging capabilites (including backtrace) out of the box!